# Error: Error in parsing: ... Line 212: Unexpected token => while doing gulp serve

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Facing an issue while using `=>`

```
incomingDemandCodes.findIndex(record => record.a === b[0].a);
```

in place of

```
incomingDemandCodes.findIndex(function (record){
  return  record.a === b[0].a;
});
```

where `b` & `incomingDemandCodes` are the arrays a as one property.

and the error that I receive during the Gulp serve is

> ```
> internal/streams/legacy.js:59
>   throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
>   ^
> ```
>
> Error: Error in parsing: "bay-status\editDemand-dialog.controller.js", Line 212: Unexpected token =>

Comment: What is your node version? Needs to be 4 or higher, otherwise arrow functions are not supported

Comment: v6.10.3 version of node @D.Simon